# What and why following two with same apply() functionality differ in their results?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, python-applymap

Objective is to convert each string to uppercase in Pandas dataframe (`df`).
Used following 3 approaches but not sure why 1st is NOT working ?
Please refer code snippet and 3 dataframes viz `df1`, `df2`, `df3`.
Using pandas.**version** == 2.1.1

```
import pandas as pd

# create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'C0': [1, 2, 3], 'C1': ['a', 'b', 'c']})

# apply lambda function to each element of the dataframe
df1 = df.apply(lambda x: x.upper() if isinstance(x, str) else x)
print(df1, '\n')

# convert all elements of the dataframe to strings and then convert them to uppercase
df2 = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.upper())
print(df2, '\n')

# applymap lambda function to each element of the dataframe
df3 = df.applymap(lambda x: x.upper() if isinstance(x, str) else x)
print(df3, '\n')


   C0 C1
0   1  a
1   2  b
2   3  c 

  C0 C1
0  1  A
1  2  B
2  3  C 

   C0 C1
0   1  A
1   2  B
2   3  C
```

1. Why outputs differ in `df1` and `df2`?
2. Why we need to cast the type of each column into string as in `df2`?
3. Why `apply()` doesn't work in `df1` but `applymap()` worked with `df3` where it checks each column datatype as string with `isinstance()`

Comment: Note that `applymap` will be deprecated  and so in  Pandas 2.1.1 you will get a warning to use `map` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Why `apply()` doesn't work in `df1`

[`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) by default applies a function to `axis=0` (to each column), where each column is of type `pd.Series`, so it does not pass the check `if isinstance(x, str)` and remains as is.

> Why we need to cast the type of each column into string as in `df2`?

You don't actually have to, as you expect to apply changes to a distinct concrete column. Unless you expect to change multiple `str` columns at once:

```
df1 = df.assign(C1=df['C1'].str.upper())
print(df1, '\n')
```

---

```
   C0 C1
0   1  A
1   2  B
2   3  C
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the second and third example outputs are exactly the same, I assume you'd like to understand why the first approach doesn't work.  The simple answer is in the statement  `df.apply(lambda x: x.upper() if isinstance(x, str) else x)` the variable x is not a single item but either a row object or a column object.  Since the type of x is not a string, the `x.Upper()` is never run.